# Fax Field not showing

Tags: magento2, address

When you save a customers address trough API you have the option to `GetFax()` and `SetFax()` but if i look at my backend i don't see Fax anywhere in the addresses

Anyone any idea if there is a setting or something to enable/disable that field?

[image]

Even though i do find that field in the database and i can `SetFax()` that field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Configuration->Customers->Customer Configuration->Name and Address Options and set 'Show Fax' To optional or Required

[image]

Comment: There is no such option to set "Fax" filed exist in configurations

Comment: It does exist. Mr downvote. A nice big circle for you. Now check your Magento version. Update it and ssht

Answer (score -1):

It is disable in database, to enable it run the following sql command

```
UPDATE `customer_eav_attribute` SET `is_visible` = '1' WHERE `customer_eav_attribute`.`attribute_id` = 35;
```

note: 35 is attribute id of Fax.

there is no option to set Fax filed in configurations

[image]

Comment: the attribute ID is not always 35. And i know how to edit the EAV attributes in the database but this is not best practice nor a solution. Thanks for the effort but can not stress enough to other people reading this then they can not run this query unless they know how the EAV attribute tables work

Comment: @SwAt.Be If you have fixed this please then  share the solution.

Comment: sure i will give it